# Need help on rich:fileUpload issue on Linux

Tags: javascript, jsf, file-upload, richfaces

I'm using rich:fileUpload in my application on linux when I try to upload any file containing html code in file name i.e `"file<img src=xyz onerror=alert('TEST')>Name.png"`, it gives me javascript alert before uploading the file. I tried it on live demo and found the same issue there as well. How can I restrict/escape execution of html/script or XSS in file name on linux?

You can try it yourself by following steps on linux.

Create a file with name `"file<img src=xyz onerror=alert('TEST')>Name.png"`
Access rich:fileUpload demo on richfaces showcase using below url.
Upload file and you will see a javascript alert.

http://showcase.richfaces.org:8000/richfaces/component-sample.jsf?demo=fileUpload&skin=blueSky

Comment: I fail to understand the problem. I get an expected javascript alert that only certain types are supported if I select a pdf file (doing that from Linux)

Comment: Ok, I misunderstood the problem, does this work on Windows or Mac?

Comment: In windows we doesn't add file name with '<' or '>'.

Comment: How **does** it add the filename then on windows?

Answer (score -1):

> I try to upload any file containing html code in file name i.e
>   "fileName.png".

You are saying html code in file name, but I don't see any html in "fileName.png".

If I'm not wrong file name should be something like `file<img src=x onerror=alert('Javascript')>.pdf`.